# Prove that the only eigenvalue of a nilpotent operator is 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nilpotence

I need to prove that:

> if a linear operator $\phi : V \rightarrow V$ on a vector space is nilpotent, then its only eigenvalue is $0$.

I know how to prove that this for a nilpotent matrix, but I'm not sure in the case of an operator. How would I be able to relate $\phi$ to a matrix?

**Note:** A nilpotent operator $\phi$ has been defined as an operator that satisfies $\phi^{n} = 0$ for some $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Choosing a basis for $V$ allows you to identify $\phi$ with a matrix, but this isn't optimal. As eigenvalues and nilpotency are defined identically for matrices and operators, the exact same proof should work.

Comment: It just makes my proof look a little sloppy though? Should I start by saying something like 'Consider the nilpotent matrix $A$, where $A^{n} = 0$ for some $n \geq 1$' and then provide the proof for a nilpotent matrix?

Comment: Hint: suppose $\phi v=\lambda v$.

Comment: @Mathlete I don't see why - I think it's much cleaner to not use matrices. As Rhys points out in his answer, this also works in the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: That does look like a better proof.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

$\phi$ is nilpotent, so $\phi^n = 0$ for some $n$.  Now let $v$ be an eigenvector: $\phi v = \lambda v$ for some scalar $\lambda$.  Now we get
$$
0 = \phi^n v = \lambda^n v ~\Rightarrow~ \lambda=0 ~.
$$

Note that this works in the infinite-dimensional case as well; there is no need to relate $\phi$ to a matrix.

*Edit*: As suggested in the comments, we can also show that $0$ is *always* an eigenvalue; in other words, $\phi$ always has at least one eigenvector.  Take any $v \neq 0$; we know that $\phi^n v = 0$, so let $k$ be the largest integer such that $\phi^k v \neq 0$.  Then $\phi(\phi^k v) = 0$, so $\phi^k v$ is an eigenvector of $\phi$, with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: For completeness, we might want to show that $0$ is actually an eigenvalue. If $v$ is injective then $\phi v \ne 0$ for every $v \ne 0$. If we choose any nonzero $v$ then $\phi^n v \ne 0$, which is a contradiction. Therefore $\ker\phi \ne \{0\}$, and any element of $\ker\phi$ is obviously an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: Yes, I probably should have added that part; I will do so, with a different wording.

Answer (score 18):

Suppose that $\phi$ has another eigenvalue $\lambda \ne 0$ so that $\phi(x)=\lambda x $ ($x$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$)

Then, $ \phi^n (x)= \phi^{(n-1)}(\phi(x))=\phi^{(n-1)}(\lambda x)=\lambda \phi^{n-1}(x)=\cdots=\lambda ^{n}x\ne 0$.

We have a contradiction, so $\phi$ can't have another eigenvalue except $0$.