# Given is a linear map.., is zero an eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> $A$ is the linear mapping $f(x)= Ax,\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
>
> $$f\left( \begin{pmatrix} x_{1}\\  x_{2}\\  x_{3}
> \end{pmatrix}\right)= \begin{pmatrix} x_{2}-x_{3}\\ 
> x_{1}+3x_{2}-2x_{3}\\  x_{1}-4x_{2}+5x_{3} \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Is zero an eigenvalue of $A$?

I need the matrix $A$. I think we can get it by forming the thing above? So

$$A= \begin{pmatrix}
0 &  1  & -1\\ 
1 &  3  & -2\\ 
1 & -4  &  5
\end{pmatrix}$$

I hope this is correct, if not everything else coming now will be wrong :s

$$\begin{vmatrix}
-\lambda &  1 & -1\\
1 &  3-\lambda & -2\\ 
1 & -4 &  5-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}
\begin{matrix}
-\lambda &  1 \\ 
1 &  3-\lambda \\ 
1 & -4
\end{matrix}$$

Characteristic polynomial $p_{A}(\lambda)= -\lambda(3-\lambda)(5-\lambda)+(-2)+4-(-(3-\lambda))-(-8\lambda)-(5-\lambda)$

$p_{A}(\lambda)= (-3\lambda+\lambda^{2})(5-\lambda)+2-(-3+\lambda)+8\lambda-5+\lambda$

$p_{A}(\lambda)= -15\lambda +3\lambda^{2}+5\lambda^{2}-\lambda^{3}+2+3-\lambda+8\lambda-5+\lambda$

$p_{A}(\lambda)= -\lambda^{3}+8\lambda^{2}-7\lambda$

We quickly see that $\lambda=0$ so zero is really an eigenvalue of $A$?

Is it correct? I especially wasn't sure at the beginning if I formed it to a matrix correctly because I didn't work with these.. mappings? in combination with matrix before.

Comment: By definition of eigenvalue, $0$ is one of $f$ if there exists a non-null vector $v$ such that $f( v)=0\cdot v$. This is equivalent to there existing a non-null vector $v$ such that $f(v)=0_{\mathbb R^3}$. One can even eyeball such a $v$. I didn't check your work, but yes, $0$ is an eigenvalue of $f$.

Comment: Remember that the product of a matrix’s eigenvalues is equal to its determinant, so *every* singular matrix has $0$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: Null vector appears in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185048/did-i-do-it-correctly-whats-the-image-and-the-basis-of-the-image-of-this-lineahttps://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185048/did-i-do-it-correctly-whats-the-image-and-the-basis-of-the-image-of-this-linea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may seem unusual that zero is an eigenvalue for your matrix, however it is allowed. If you look at your characteristic polynomial $ - \lambda ^3 + 8 \lambda ^2 - 7 \lambda  = -\lambda ( \lambda ^2 + 8 \lambda - 7 ) $, you see that zero is indeed a root for this polynomial - you just have to find the corresponding eigenvector.

There are certain matrices actually that only have zero as an eigenvalue - namely nilpotent matrices, it may be worth having a look at the proof: [Prove that the only eigenvalue of a nilpotent operator is 0?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372370/prove-that-the-only-eigenvalue-of-a-nilpotent-operator-is-0)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, given your matrix $A$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & -1\\ 
1 & 3 & -2\\ 
1 & -4 & 5\\ 
\end{array}
\right)$$

by inspection the vector  $$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
-1 \\ 1\\ 1\\ 
\end{array}
\right)$$

is an eigenvector of $A$ with the required eigenvalue you are uncertain about $(0)$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the operation $C_1\rightarrow C_1-C_2-C_3$ produces a zero column in first place hence det($A$)$=0$. So $0$ must be an eigenvalue.